# Zend Framework 2 Restful web service: common functionality across controllers

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

Im making a restful web service with Zend FW 2. How can I create a system, that checks ie. API key everytime REST is called? Checking the key in every controller in every function of course is not the way to go, so Im looking for something "global".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all your rest methods are in one controller you can listen to that controllers dispatch event, using a high priority so checks are done early...

Register the listener in your modules bootstrap, for example assuming you added an `ApiController` to the `Application` module

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    // get the shared events manager 
    $sem = $app->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    // listen to dispatch event when triggered by the ApiController
    $sem->attach('Application\Controller\ApiController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
        // do your api key checks

        // if checks fail get the response from the controller
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $response = $controller->getResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(401);
        // return $response, short circuiting dispatch event
        return $response;
    }, 9000); // 9000 = high priority, do this early
}
```

Point of note, the event passed to your closure contains as its target an instance of your controller, so if you need to get services from the ServiceManager to do your api checks you can do so just like you would in the controller itself, ie...

```
 $controller = $e->getTarget();
 $sm = $controller->getServiceLocator();
```

Comment: My rest methods are in multiple controllers, but they all extend the original RestfulController, so maybe I would be able to listen that? This infact is the thing I tried, mut I didn't know that you can set the priority.

Comment: That should work, yeah. You can hand the shared event manager a list of controllers too, `$sem->attach(array('Application\Controller\ApiController', 'Application\Controller\OtherController'), 'dispatch',  ...`